# Will correcting other users' questions remove my question ban?

Tags: discussion, edits, post-ban

After the question ban I have had during these days, I tried editing questions (not my own) and gained some reputation.

Will it have any effect on removing the question ban?

Please don't mention editing my own questions. I know that and that has had quite a contrary effect so far.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197613/discussion-on-question-by-fabiospaghetti-will-correcting-other-users-questions).

Answer (score 12):

Gaining reputation (overall) will help expedite lifting of the block. We don't reveal the algorithms directly because doing so would cause folks to focus on the wrong stuff, but a main theme in all of them (there are multiple, including the one that tried to slow you down for a few days) is your average question score over time; that's what makes them very difficult to game, and sometimes escape in extreme cases.

The system *does* acknowledge any attempt you make at editing your own questions and it reflects favorably when evaluating some of the blocks. So *if* a question is on-topic and can be salvaged, the fact that you *tried* to edit will work in your favor, though it frequently won't be enough by itself to push you over the threshold. You do need some upvotes, and upvotes that the system deems suspicious won't be counted (some of us should really design video games).

I checked, and you're not blocked any longer *but you're right at the edge*. Try to make your next question *really* count, and you should be out of the woods for good.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. With the only comment that video games are a pleasure, correcting questions not

Comment: @Tim Would somebody else editing and improving the questions of somebody with a question ban help expedite lifting the block? Indirectly probably yes because of a potentially higher score.

Comment: @Trilarion Indirectly yes. I haven't looked at the code for a while, but a suggested edit that was improved and accepted by the OP can also help, especially in the early stages of blocks where we just really slow folks down by making them wait increasingly longer to ask more questions. Suffice it to say, score is important, and some detectable effort by the OP to at least try and edit things helps too. But, if something is just blatantly off-topic, no amount of editing is really going to help, so it depends.

Comment: @TimPost What if I have too many posts that are unsalvageable? Should I focus on the ones that aren't?

Comment: @BlueRobin I don't know what the parameters are for the blocks any longer, but I can't imagine that you're far from the threshold at all. You could try contacting support one more time, pointing them toward your badges and the amount of positive participation that you have, and request that they disassociate one of the unsalvageable posts from your account. They may agree that it's better to do that than force you to make another and abandon all your positive contributions too. It's their call, though - this is a sort of exception. Good luck!

Comment: @TimPost Thanks! Hopefully, support will give me mercy.

Comment: @TimPost They did! I'm unbanned now. Just gotta make sure I don't skrew up again, and I learn from my mistakes. Thanks!